# How to transform Oracle DateTime to Date

Tags: sql, oracle

For instance, I have a datetime like this `'2016-04-02 00:00:00'` and another like this `'2016-04-02 15:10:00'`. I don't care about the time-part, I want them to match just by the date-part.

I have tried with `date()`, `to_date`, `datepart`, nothing works.

Comment: I'm curious .. why do you need to do this? what larger problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: what is `your` datetime? what is `your` date? Please show example or something like your desire goal

Comment: Because i have a condition who have to match with the date of a datetime... but it's not necesary to match the part time. I hope you see what i mean.

Comment: trunc(<your datetime>).  There is no such thing as an oracle date with no time component.  Oracle DATE data types is date/time.  Trunc will set the time to 00:00:00.

Comment: @servatj, based on your response, OlDProgrammer has answered your question .. no conversion needed, just TRUNC() ..

Comment: What you've shown are strings; what data type(s) are you really working with? Are they values in two tables? Comparing a table value with a fixed date? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncating the date to day should do the trick. Documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm

For example

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DAY') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
 where yourField >= the start of your date range
 and yourField < the day after the end of your date range
```

**Edit starts here:**

While you could use `trunc`, as suggested by others, bear in mind that filtering on function results tends to be slow.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said - there is no separate "date" data type in Oracle. A pure "date" is stored as a date with the time portion set to 00:00:00 (midnight at the beginning of the day), and TRUNC(*date*) will take any date and truncate the time to 00:00:00, so if you need to compare two dates you can write

```
where trunc(date_1) = trunc(date_2)
```

If your tables are very large and you need to do these comparisons often, this is not ideal, because wrapping column values within function calls (like date_1 within a TRUNC) prevents the use of an index you may have on the date_1 column. If you need to compare dates in two columns you may not have much of a choice, but if you compare to a fixed date (or something like SYSDATE) you may be better off with something like

```
where date_1 >= trunc(sysdate) and date_1 < trunc(sysdate) + 1
```

Here you are not using trunc on the column value, so if there's an index on the column, Oracle is free to use it - and trunc(sysdate) is computed only once, not for every single row. "+1" by the way means "add one day".

TO_DATE converts a string to a date; if you apply TO_DATE to a value that is already a legitimate date, you will get unexpected results because Oracle will first convert your true date to a string and then back to date again, and since these conversions require a date FORMAT for strings, and the formats Oracle assumes for conversion from date to string and from string to date may not match, .... you get the idea. As far as I know, DATE() (a FUNCTION) and DATEPART do not exist in Oracle; when you use a new language, keep Google close by and use it often.

If you input a date with no time component, for example `TO_DATE('04-apr-2016, 'dd-mon-yyyy')`, then the implicit time is 00:00:00 so you don't need to apply TRUNC() to it.

Good luck!